# Path slashes disappear on coloured bash prompt

Tags: ubuntu, bash, colors, gnome-terminal

So in my .bashrc, I set my prompt to be colourful by setting `PS1` to

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$
```

For some reason, all the slashes in the current directory path appear as spacesinstead of being '/'. E.g., with a standard `\u@\h:\w$` prompt I see: `adam@ubuntu:~/bin$` whereas with the colourful prompt, I see: `adam@morpheus:~ tmp` even though when I copy and paste the text is the same.

I'm only seeing the problem with the standard Gnome terminal, it seems to work fine with other terminals like xterm or the Mac OS X terminal.

Any ideas?